# What does this mark mean? (Characters identified: 周桂珍制)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Could someone please help me with the mark on this yixing teapot please?

[image: chop mark on a chinese teapot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 珍　周
>
> 制　桂

Made by 周桂珍, craftswoman born in Yixing in 1943. You can [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHWA_enNZ604NZ604&biw=1920&bih=937&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNRnjPJaVYTR-riCFP2x8XqdlKEvUQ%3A1574308089435&sa=1&ei=-QjWXbOEGpG88QOZ6LTQCQ&q=%E5%91%A8%E6%A1%82%E7%8F%8D&oq=%E5%91%A8%E6%A1%82%E7%8F%8D&gs_l=img.3..35i39j0l9.3378.3378..3786...0.0..0.212.212.2-1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.mLLWwuhHfsk&ved=0ahUKEwjz5L_TsvrlAhURXnwKHRk0DZoQ4dUDCAc&uact=5) the name to get more pictures of teapots.

Comment: Oh thank you so very much I really appreciate it!